# Relay/Send through NAT in Python

Tags: python, networking, routes

I'm looking for a solution to exchange data (protocols build on TCP) between NAT separated endpoints - more or less directly.

- I can setup a relay service for example - which is what I have in mind. However I want to route traffic without losing too much performance.
- or I can build a VPN with a central VPN server

Are there optimised libraries in Python to allow me forwarding and building a relay server - for example. Or is there something more elegant that doesn't even require a node in the middle? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about Python implementations, but you may want to look at Samy Kamkar's example implementations of mechanisms for relay-free NAT traversal when both endpoints are NATed. (and the papers he references)

- [pwnat](http://samy.pl/pwnat/)
- [chownat](http://samy.pl/chownat/)
- [NAT Pinning](http://samy.pl/natpin/)